# How to plot multiple pie chart or bar chart from multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, pie-chart

Dataframe is as below.

There are multiple index as `category_1` & `category_2` and two column as `count` & `%`

I need to draw multiple (for each `category_1`) pie chart for `category_2` & `%` and bar chart for `category_2` & `count`.

|  |  | count | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| category_1 | category_2 |  |  |
| Bady and Kids | Baby Care | 220 | 27.5 |
|  | Toys | 176 | 22 |
|  | Boys Clothing | 156 | 19.5 |
|  | Girls Clothing | 144 | 18 |
|  | Baby Boy Clothing | 104 | 13 |
| Women's wear | Party Dresses | 224 | 28 |
|  | Sports Wear | 188 | 23.5 |
|  | Swim wear | 140 | 17.5 |
|  | Winter Wear | 128 | 16 |
|  | Watches | 120 | 15 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#gt number of groups first for subplots
no = len(df.index.levels[0])
fig, axes = plt.subplots(no, 2, figsize=(10, 6))

#for each group by first level of Multiindex
for i, (name, g) in enumerate(df.groupby(level=0)):
    #remove first level and index name
    g = g.droplevel(0).rename_axis(None)

    #get positions dynamic
    ax =  axes[i, 0]
    ax1 = axes[i, 1]

    #plot both graphs together
    g['count'].plot.pie(ax=ax, legend=False)
    ax.set_title(f'{name} %')
    g['%'].plot.bar(ax=ax1, legend=False, rot=45)
    ax1.set_title(f'{name} count')

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.2)
```

---

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for cat1, subdf in df.groupby(level='category_1'):
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
    subdf.loc[cat1, :].plot.pie(y='count', ax=ax1, ylabel='', legend=False)
    subdf.loc[cat1, :].plot.bar(y='%', ax=ax2, rot=45, xlabel='', legend=False)
    fig.suptitle(cat1)
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

[image]